# MySQL query is causing Windows MySQL Service to stop running

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having an issue where I run a query and it crashes my MySQL service. What is causing this? It seems to be just this query, other basic queries it runs just fine.

I just upgraded from **5.7.x** to **8.0.15**, and it worked on **5.7.x**

**MySQL Server Version:** 8.0.15

> SQL Error (2013): Lost connection to MySQL server during query

```sql
SELECT  `id`, `data`, count(*) as `abc123` 
FROM documents where  MATCH (data) AGAINST ('abc' in natural language mode)
```

The table looks like this (it's an empty table):

```sql
CREATE TABLE `documents` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `data` TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    FULLTEXT INDEX `data` (`data`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=3;
```

Here is the crash log:

```
2019-04-02T22:52:45.347214Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010915] [Server] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
2019-04-02T22:52:45.349797Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.15) starting as process 6428
2019-04-02T22:52:47.918771Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2019-04-02T22:52:48.007761Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.15'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2019-04-02T22:52:48.164752Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060
22:52:51 UTC - mysqld got exception 0xc0000005 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Attempting to collect some information that could help diagnose the problem.
As this is a crash and something is definitely wrong, the information
collection process might fail.

key_buffer_size=8388608
read_buffer_size=65536
max_used_connections=1
max_threads=151
thread_count=2
connection_count=1
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 58027 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x252d8546db0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
7ff6e68a862f    mysqld.exe!??1?$lock_guard@Vmutex@std@@@std@@QEAA@XZ()
7ff6e5a91b7e    mysqld.exe!?ha_ft_read@handler@@QEAAHPEAE@Z()
7ff6e5e3a44a    mysqld.exe!?Read@FullTextSearchIterator@@UEAAHXZ()
7ff6e5e43756    mysqld.exe!?sub_select@@YA?AW4enum_nested_loop_state@@PEAVJOIN@@PEAVQEP_TAB@@_N@Z()
7ff6e5e3ca97    mysqld.exe!?deallocate@?$allocator@PEA_N@std@@QEAAXQEAPEA_N_K@Z()
7ff6e5e3eddd    mysqld.exe!?exec@JOIN@@QEAAXXZ()
7ff6e5d03d0c    mysqld.exe!?execute_inner@Sql_cmd_dml@@MEAA_NPEAVTHD@@@Z()
7ff6e5d03a80    mysqld.exe!?execute@Sql_cmd_dml@@UEAA_NPEAVTHD@@@Z()
7ff6e5c2375f    mysqld.exe!?mysql_execute_command@@YAHPEAVTHD@@_N@Z()
7ff6e5c24217    mysqld.exe!?mysql_parse@@YAXPEAVTHD@@PEAVParser_state@@_N@Z()
7ff6e5c1dd64    mysqld.exe!?dispatch_command@@YA_NPEAVTHD@@PEBTCOM_DATA@@W4enum_server_command@@@Z()
7ff6e5c1ecf7    mysqld.exe!?do_command@@YA_NPEAVTHD@@@Z()
7ff6e5a8a328    mysqld.exe!?kill_blocked_pthreads@Per_thread_connection_handler@@SAXXZ()
7ff6e6b73297    mysqld.exe!??$endl@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@YAAEAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AEAV10@@Z()
7ff6e67ddf6c    mysqld.exe!?my_thread_join@@YAHPEAUmy_thread_handle@@PEAPEAX@Z()
7ffd0367e3fe    ucrtbase.dll!_o_strcat_s()
7ffd04e03dc4    KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk()
7ffd064f3691    ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (252dba82a08): SELECT  `id`, `data`, count(*) as `abc123` 
FROM documents where  MATCH (data) AGAINST ('abc' in natural language mode)
Connection ID (thread ID): 8
Status: NOT_KILLED

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

Comment: A minor aside, but if you're using `COUNT()` you're going to need a `GROUP BY` clause too.

Comment: Not if I want to count everything...

Comment: But would you not expect to get multiple results from the search?

Comment: If I remove `id` and `data` the query no longer crashes the server

Comment: You should check out mysql and windows error logs if they have any further details regarding the crash. The problem is with this question is that you either stumbled on a bug or there are some unique circumstances that cause the error. Both are pretty difficult to sort out here on SO.

Comment: I have added the crash log

Comment: Unless you work for mysql, this crash log does not mean too much. You should post this to mysql's forum or raise a mysql bug report. You are lot more likely to get an answer there.

Comment: I have reported this as a bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=94892

Comment: Looks like it is a known bug which they are calling a `Security Vulnerability`.

Comment: Since you know the table is empty - could this be the problem?  Add a row to the table that will cause you to have a reportable item and see if MySQL survives the query.  If MySQL survives the query when you have useful data, update your bug report, please for the team to know what to look for when a table is empty.

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
RAM size of your MySQL Host server 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 2 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server basic tuning analysis.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn 8.0.15 has posted General Availability date of 02/01/2019.  In the future, you may wish to consider delaying implementation until GA date + 90 days (or 180 days) to allow 'someone else' the privilege of discovering/reporting a problem that is obscure.  Here is the url, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-15.html